# Trouble with Synchronization in android social media application

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
public class HomePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String[] friends;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Activity functions
        FriendWorker fw = new FriendWorker();
        fw.execute(...);
    }

    public void setFriends(String[] friends) {
        this.friends = Arrays.copyOf(friends, friends.length);
    }

    public class FriendWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //get and return result
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            setFriends(friendsArray);
        }

    }
}
```

I know I am getting the correct result from the doInBackground and onPostExecute does call and set the friends array that I have declared in the HomePageActivity however when it exits out the FriendWorker it doesn't keep the values that it set. I think that's why it is a synchronization issue. I don't have much experience with synchronization or async would appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a print statement, an log statement or a debugger to find out what `result` and `friends` contain.  From what I can see, you are not checking the response status from the HTTP request, so you could be "parsing" an error message or something.

Comment: Also, you haven't explained why this has anything to do with synchronization.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear enough, I believe this is a synchronization issue because I think that the asynctask makes a new thread in order to execute the http connection so I believe the problem is that this and the rest of the android application aren't being executed on the same thread. I have tried thoroughly degubbing and printing statements to make sure that the result is what desire.

Comment: Well it could be a synchronization problem, but you haven't provided enough information to allow a proper diagnosis.  Please create an MCVE for this and add it to your Question.

Comment: I tried updating what I uploaded with the format you requested. Hopefully that helps in seeing what exactly is going on. Thank you in advance.